# Difference between Powershell 5.1 and Powershell 7 certificate encyption using same code

Tags: powershell, jwt, certificate, p12

i am trying to generate a JWT token from a already created p12 cert (from google) using Powershell 5.1. It works fine in Powershell 7. But i have noticed that Powershell 5.1 encrypts the private key in a different way and this causes me errors in the following new-jwt commands. Cert names are not real - only a p12 cert is required to replicate.

```
#Public
     # normal method for getting the cert details (PS 6 and above only) - can't use this as -password param is only PS6 and above
     #$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath 'C:\gsuite-325413-4e17f897eees.p12' -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString "notasecret" -AsPlainText -Force)
    
    #Generate JWT using a p12 cert on PS 5.1 (cert names changed) using dot net - Different result with these 3 lines on 5.1 and PS 7.
    $certfilepath = 'C:\gsuite-325413-4e17f897eees.p12'
    $SecStrPass =  ConvertTo-SecureString -string "notasecret" -AsPlainText -Force
    $cert = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 ($certfilepath,$SecStrPass,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"DefaultKeySet")

 #Note the KeyExchangeAlgorithm
 $cert.PrivateKey

 #Result on PS5.1:
#PublicOnly           : False
#CspKeyContainerInfo  : System.Security.Cryptography.CspKeyContainerInfo
#KeySize              : 2048
#KeyExchangeAlgorithm : RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx
#SignatureAlgorithm   : http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
#PersistKeyInCsp      : True
#LegalKeySizes        : {System.Security.Cryptography.KeySizes}

#PS 7 with same (dot net) code
#    Key                  : System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey
#LegalKeySizes        : {System.Security.Cryptography.KeySizes}
#KeyExchangeAlgorithm : RSA
#SignatureAlgorithm   : RSA
#KeySize              : 2048
```

I need to generate a RSA KeyExchangeAlgorithm running Powershell 5.1, is there any way i can do this?

Just for info (as Colyn1337 requested it) the error i later get using new-jwt function is the following but its just failing on encryption type if the private key is signed in sha1. The issue remains a difference of encryption using the same code on the same machine with the same certificate - just PS version is different.

```
Signing with SHA256 and Pkcs1 padding failed using private key System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider: 
Exception calling "SignData" with "3" argument(s): "Invalid algorithm specified.
```

Comment: Helps if you include the errors you get and the code that generates them ;)

Comment: As mentioned, I don't get any errors I get a difference of encryption using the same code on the same machine with the same certificate. I am asking if anyone knows why or what i can do to fix it. The code is provided. I am guessing its because PS5.1 are using .net framework and ps7 .net core. The new-jwt error later in the script is just caused by the difference of encryption - this isn't that relevant but i have updated the ticket to include it.

Comment: I don't think your problem is encryption but the cryptographic service provider.  You've uploaded the error which lends substance to my theory, but you're still not giving us complete code.  So, I'll point you to a MS doc to illustrate the CSP differences and you can go from there, best of luck to you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography

Comment: Thanks for the link that was helpful. I think you are correct about the cryptographic service provider. I think the 'new-object' line is using CAPI when on PS5.1/.net Framework 4.8 but CNG when using PS7/.net 5. I suppose i am asking anyone  is there any way to force .net Framewokr to use CNG for the Powershell session?

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10833